# Urls with url params not being resolved in create-react-app-rewired app with multiple entry point

Tags: webpack, create-react-app, html-webpack-plugin

I have the following configuration in config-override.js file to achieve multiple entry points.

```
config.entry = {
    index: [
      config.entry[0],  // polyfill.js
      paths.appSrc + '/entryPoints/somePath1/AppPage1.tsx'
    ],
    appPage1: [
      config.entry[0],  // polyfill.js
      paths.appSrc + '/entryPoints/somePath1/AppPage1.tsx'
   ],
  appPage2: [
     config.entry[0],  // polyfill.js
     paths.appSrc + '/entryPoints/somePath2/AppPage2.tsx'
  ],
 ...
}


new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  hash: true,
  template: paths.appHtml,
  chunks: ['index'],
  filename: paths.appBuild + '/index.html'
}),
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  hash: true,
  template: paths.appHtml,
  chunks: ['appPage1'],
  filename: paths.appBuild + '/page1/index.html'
}),
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  hash: true,
  template: paths.appPublic + '/page2.html',
  chunks: ['appPage2'],
  filename: paths.appBuild + '/abc/page2.html'
})
```

The problem I am facing is the url http://localhost:5000/abc/page2.html works but http://localhost:5000/abc/page2.html?someUrlParam=someValue results in the incorrect page/entry(page1) is being returned.

If I do hard refresh for url http://localhost:5000/abc/page2.html?someUrlParam=someValue it works as expected in normal chrome window but not in incognito mode.

I am getting same behaviour after ejection and using the equivalent entry points and HtmlWebpackPlugin entries.

Update:
The problem was solved by [unregistering](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#opting-out-of-caching) service worker an removing it.

But its not clear why removing url params was resulting in expected behaviour.
May be following comment in [webpack.config.prod.js](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/next/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.prod.js) has something to do with it

`// By default, a cache-busting query parameter is appended to requests
    // used to populate the caches, to ensure the responses are fresh.
    // If a URL is already hashed by Webpack, then there is no concern
    // about it being stale, and the cache-busting can be skipped`